# Regex and find in text file

Tags: java, regex

I have this code :

```
package ggg;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.*;

public class regex {
     public static void main( String args[] ){

          // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
          String line = "This order was placed FRO-DDA-6666666 %10.25 %10.12 FRO-DDA-8888888 for QT3000! OK?";
          String pattern = "\\d+\\.\\d{2}";
          String pattern2 = "\\d{7}";


          // Create a Pattern object
          Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
          Pattern t = Pattern.compile(pattern2);

          // Now create matcher object.
          Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
          Matcher g = t.matcher(line);
          try {
          PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\John\\workspace\\ggg\\src\\ggg\\text.txt", "UTF-8");
          for (int i = 1; m.find() && g.find(); i++) {
             writer.println(g.group(0)+"->"+m.group(0));
          }
          writer.close();
          } catch (IOException ex) {}
       }

}
```

And result is: 
6666666->10.25

8888888->10.12

I want to write a simple code to read text.txt file and if "8888888" exist in this file then print what is the front of "8888888->", What should I do ? 
For example in our result 10.12 is front of 888888->

Comment: i don't understand the question. your example produces the value 10.12. where is the problem

Comment: I don't have any problem I want a simple code or simple algorithm that read text.txt file and if "8888888" exist in this file then print what is the front of "8888888->"

Comment: so you want it to read from file then display 10.12  because it's contained in the same line as 8888888-> ?

Comment: @MihaiC: yeah, Just display what is the front of 8888888->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your code after building the file:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\John\\workspace\\ggg\\src\\ggg\\text.txt"));
    String myLine;
    while ((myLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
       if(myLine.contains("8888888"))
           System.out.println(myLine.substring(myLine.indexOf(">")+1));
    }
    br.close();
```

Comment: Or as regular expression: [8]{7} :D. This question is....